# What's behind ESPN having such high quality streaming for the World Cup through Flash?

Tags: flash, bandwidth, p2p, soundcloud-stratus

I'm aware of [Stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) which is used for ChatRoulette with a requirement of Flash 10. Does anyone happen to know if ESPN uses the same technology or is it just the sheer amount of servers they have which makes this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](http://www.flashstreamworks.com/archive.php?post_id=1276261019) it's a combination of the new FMS3.5, adaptive bitrate streaming, Flex 4 and [OSMF](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/). I guess the performance/quality wins comes from the adaptive bitrates? Nothing about stratus, though, and that blog is from an Adobe evangelist, so I guess he'd have mentioned if it was involved. All together pretty damned impressive though, I agree.